# OCaml のクラスにポリモーフィックな map メソッドを持たせたい

Tags: ocaml

次のようなmapメソッドが作れなくて困っています

```
class ['a] my_ref (x_init : 'a) =
object
  val mutable x = x_init
  method get = x
  method set y = x <- y
  method map : 'b. ('a -> 'b) -> 'b my_ref = fun f -> new my_ref (f x)
end
```

エラーメッセージは

```
Error: The universal type variable 'b cannot be generalized:
       it escapes its scope.
```

です。'b の量化を消すと通りますが、'a と 'b が同じ型になってしまいます。

元々の問題は js_of_ocaml の
https://github.com/ocsigen/js_of_ocaml/blob/2.6/lib/js.mli#L296
がポリモーフィックになってないのでバグレポートを送りたいのですが、js_of_ocaml 側がどうにか工夫すれば対応できる問題なのか知りたいのです。

Comment: かじっただけなのでわかりませんが、単純な `class type ['a] ct = object method m : 'b. 'b ct end` というクラス型定義が撥ねられるので、polymorphic な自分自身を型を返すメソッドは作れないと理解しています。これが通るとまずい例を知らないのでこれ以上は私はわかりません。 caml-list で聞くと良いと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

これが通るとまずいというよりも、こういう型を許すと型推論ができなくなります。OCamlは再帰型を正則なもの(型パラメーターの変わらないもの)にすることで、型推論を可能にしています。上のような非正則なものまで許すとぐんと難しくなります。ICALPの20年前の言語理論の論文によれば、扱える可能性がありますが、現実的なアルゴリズムはありません。
ちなみに、構造的な再帰型の代わりに、生成的なものを使うと、再帰の推論をする必要がなくなって、非正則な型が扱えます。Haskellの型クラスやGADTでそれを利用できます。